# Get ?? for unicode characters

Tags: encoding

I'm facing a huge problem : every smileys copy from the website `emojipedia.org` appear like ?? on my website.

The HTML page charset is utf8.

The structure table in the DB (wp_posts) is  : 
[image: wp_posts]

All is working fine (accent like é è à etc.) but not something like : ✔️

This symbol appear like ?? in preview and when I save the post.

I've try to change in the `.htaccess` : 
`AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` to `AddDefaultCharset off` but without success.

Here is a part of the `.htaccess` file :

```
# BEGIN WP Rocket v3.3.4
# Use UTF-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html
AddDefaultCharset off
# Force UTF-8 for a number of file formats
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddCharset UTF-8 .atom .css .js .json .rss .vtt .xml
</IfModule>
```

In the `wp-config`, the constant `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` are not set.

Any ideas?

Comment: Which encoding/collation are the database tables themselves? It looks like they're using latin1 rather than the newer utf8mb which means any emoji get truncated/stripped on save

Comment: In the `wp-config`, the constant `DB_CHARSET` and `DB_COLLATE` are not set.

Comment: Well it definitely looks like your database is set up in a character encoding that can't store full UTF8 values, you'll need to convert that

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Converting_Database_Character_Sets